# What is the best way to concatenate a multidimensional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to populate an autocomplete search box.

I am using this, but is there a better way?

```js
var array1 = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  ['g', 'h', 'i']
];

console.log(array1[0].concat(array1[1], array1[2]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `flat()`

```js
var array1 = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  ['g', 'h', 'i']
];

console.log( array1.flat() );
```

---

Or `concat` and spread syntax

```js
var array1 = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  ['g', 'h', 'i']
];

console.log( [].concat(...array1) )
```